# Deal with partial messages using SocketAsyncEventArgs

Tags: c#, asynchronous, socket

As you know, when dealing with `SocketAsyncEventArgs`, this is possible to receive partial messages and depending on the protocol used, you have to deal with it. In my case, this is real-time market data and every messages are separated with a `\r\n` pattern. In order to reduce memory allocation, I decided to build a handler for this purpose and I wish to have your feedback. Basically, every time that I receive data, I write to the handler and check if at least I have a completed message. If yes, I push it to the upper layer. If not, wait for a second transmission and so on.

Handler Tests

```
public class MessageHandlerTests
{
    private MessageHandler _messageHandler;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        _messageHandler = new MessageHandler(8192, '\n');
    }

    [Test]
    public void TryRead_Should_Return_Positive_Count_After_Receiving_Delimeter_On_First_Write()
    {
        // Arrange
        var msg = "2008-09-30 16:29:56,26.6000,100,104865900,26.6000,26.6100,2836662,0,0,E,\r\n";
        var msgBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

        // Act
        _messageHandler.Write(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        var count = _messageHandler.TryRead(out var readBytes);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(count, msg.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBytes, 0, count), msg);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TryRead_Should_Return_Positive_Count_After_Receiving_Delimeter_On_Second_Write()
    {
        // Arrange
        var msg1 = "2008-09-30 16:29:56,26.6000,100,104865900";
        var msg2 = ",26.6000,26.6100,2836662,0,0,E,\r\n";
        var msg1Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg1);
        var msg2Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg2);

        // Act
        _messageHandler.Write(msg1Bytes, 0, msg1Bytes.Length);
        _messageHandler.Write(msg2Bytes, 0, msg2Bytes.Length);
        var count = _messageHandler.TryRead(out var readBytes);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(count, msg1.Length + msg2.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBytes, 0, count), msg1 + msg2);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TryRead_Should_Return_Positive_Count_After_Receiving_Delimeter_On_First_Write_With_Remainder()
    {
        // Arrange
        var msg1 = "2008-09-30 16:29:56,26.6000,100,104865900,26.6000,26.6100,2836662,0,0,E,\r\n";
        var msg2 = "2008-09-30 ";
        var msgBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg1 + msg2);

        // Act
        _messageHandler.Write(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        var count = _messageHandler.TryRead(out var readBytes);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(count, msg1.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBytes, 0, count), msg1);
    }

    [Test]
    public void TryRead_Should_Return_Positive_Count_After_Receiving_Delimeter_On_Second_Write_With_Remainder()
    {
        // Arrange
        var msg1 = "2008-09-30 16:29:56,26.6000,100,104865900";
        var msg2 = ",26.6000,26.6100,2836662,0,0,E,\r\n";
        var msg3 = "2008-09-30 ";
        var msg1Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg1);
        var msg2Bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg2 + msg3);

        // Act
        _messageHandler.Write(msg1Bytes, 0, msg1Bytes.Length);
        _messageHandler.Write(msg2Bytes, 0, msg2Bytes.Length);
        var count = _messageHandler.TryRead(out var readBytes);

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(count, msg1.Length + msg2.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(readBytes, 0, count), msg1 + msg2);
    }

    [Test]
    public void Should_Return_Zero_After_One_Succesful_TryRead()
    {
        // Arrange
        var msg = "2008-09-30 16:29:56,26.6000,100,104865900,26.6000,26.6100,2836662,0,0,E,\r\n";
        var msgBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);

        // Act
        byte[] readBytes;
        _messageHandler.Write(msgBytes, 0, msgBytes.Length);
        var count1 = _messageHandler.TryRead(out readBytes);
        var count2 = _messageHandler.TryRead(out readBytes);

        // Assert
        Assert.Greater(count1, 0);
        Assert.AreEqual(count2, 0);
    }
}
```

Handler

```
public class MessageHandler
{
    private readonly char _delimeter;

    private readonly MemoryStream _completeStream;
    private readonly MemoryStream _remainderStream;
    private readonly byte[] _readBytes;

    public MessageHandler(int bufferSize, char delimeter)
    {
        _delimeter = delimeter;

        _completeStream = new MemoryStream(bufferSize);
        _completeStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        _remainderStream = new MemoryStream(bufferSize);
        _remainderStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        _readBytes = new byte[bufferSize];
    }

    public void Write(byte[] message, int offset, int count)
    {
        // check if delimeter is found
        var delimeterIndex = message.GetLastDelimeterIndex(offset, count, _delimeter);

        // if not found, simply copy bytes into the remainder and return
        if (delimeterIndex == -1)
        {
            _remainderStream.Write(message, offset, count);
            return;
        }

        // if remainder exists, copy bytes into complete
        if (_remainderStream.Position > 0) {
            _remainderStream.WriteTo(_completeStream);
            _remainderStream.SetLength(0);
        }
        // copy received bytes with last delimeter into complete
        _completeStream.Write(message, offset, delimeterIndex + 1);

        // delimeter found at the end of the message
        if (delimeterIndex == count - 1)
            return;

        _remainderStream.Write(message, delimeterIndex + 1, count - delimeterIndex - 1);
    }

    public int TryRead(out byte[] output)
    {
        output = null;
        if (_completeStream.Position == 0)
            return 0;

        var length = (int)_completeStream.Length;
        _completeStream.Position = 0;
        _completeStream.Read(_readBytes, 0, length);
        _completeStream.SetLength(0);
        output = _readBytes;
        return length;
    }
}

public static class ByteExtensions
{
    public static int GetLastDelimeterIndex(this byte[] buffer, int offset, int length, char delimeter)
    {
        for (var i = offset + length - 1; i >= offset; i--)
        {
            if (buffer[i] == delimeter)
                return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: This might be interesting  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-server-socket-example

Comment: @paparazzo this thing is synchronous. I can't afford to block X threads for this application. I really need something with high performance profile such as SocketAsyncEventArgs developed by especially for this usage. Look at my SocketClient https://github.com/mathpaquette/IQFeed.CSharpApiClient/blob/devel/src/IQFeed.CSharpApiClient/Sockets/SocketClient.cs

Comment: wow this example is completely inefficient... appending on a string!!! cant believe it.

Comment: Ok, you did not find it interesting.

Comment: @paparazzo but anyway, thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Style is good, comments are useful, and the API is simple and general-purpose.

---

I'd appreciate a guard clause in the constructor, providing a meaningful error message if I try to misuse it.

```
if (bufferSize <= 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(bufferSize), "Buffer Size must be greater than 0");
```

Similarly, they could be added to `Write`.

---

From an API perspective, I kind of expected this to return a single message every time `TryRead` is called. It doesn't, and that's fine, but inline documention (`\\\`) would not go amiss in explaining the expected behaviour.

---

Reusing `_readBytes` and passing out from `TryRead` is a bit surprising and perhaps risky.

An alternative design with lesser memory requirements would be to pass the `MessageHandler` a stream, and just have it write to said stream when data comes in. This obsolves the class of the responsibility of maintaing a buffer (indeed, *two* buffers) and significantly simplifies the API. The `TryRead` code can them be implemented independantly and work with any `MemoryStream`. Alternatively, construct said memory stream from a byte array, and pass that out directly.

This would have fairly serious implications for threading, but I judge you arn't worried about that given your commentary and code. More important, holding onto the stream/buffer would allow a consumer to mess up future results *before* calling `TryRead` (currently they can only lose the data they have just received); but if memory is big problem then this would help.

One other alternative (which may or may not be applicable) would be to call an event whenever a complete message is read. You could do this all with a single `MemoryStream` if you trust the callbacks not to mess with it (which you already do to an extent in `TryRead`).

---

`GetLastDelimeterIndex` is not specific to Delimeters; I'd call it something more generic, like `LastIndexOfChar` (after `Array.LastIndexOf`).

---

Your tests are good, but every test of `MessageHandler.Write` expects it to consume the whole array. This means that a chunk of intricate logic is virtually untested, and is exactly the kind of code that results in hard-to-find bugs.

... indeed, there are multiple related bugs.

```
// copy received bytes with last delimeter into complete
_completeStream.Write(message, offset, delimeterIndex + 1); // should be delimeterIndex - offset + 1

if (delimeterIndex == count - 1) // should be count + offset - 1
    return;

 _remainderStream.Write(message, delimeterIndex + 1, count + offset - delimeterIndex - 1); // should be count + offset - delimeterIndex - 1
```

I found them while trying to write this test:

```
public void Partial_Writes_Are_Not_Completely_Broken()
{
    // Arrange
    var msg = "fish fish fish\r\nfox fox fox";
    var msgBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(msg);
    int startCrop = 5;
    int endCrop = 4;
    int delimiterIndex = msg.LastIndexOf('\n');

    // Act
    byte[] readBytes;
    _messageHandler.Write(msgBytes, startCrop, msgBytes.Length - startCrop - endCrop);
    var count1 = _messageHandler.TryRead(out readBytes);
    _messageHandler.Write(msgBytes, delimiterIndex, 1);
    var count2 = _messageHandler.TryRead(out readBytes);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(count1, delimiterIndex - startCrop + 1);
    Assert.AreEqual(count2, msg.Length - delimiterIndex - endCrop);
}
```

---

Which testing framework are you using? I'm too lazy to try to work it out, but usually the *expected* value comes first in Assert calls, and the *actual* value second. This tripped me up while I was debugging the test.